# Filter 2 dimensions array and merge different values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have an array:

```
$arr = [
  ['id'=>1, 'name'=>'Peter', 'age'=>28],
  ['id'=>1, 'name'=>'David', 'age'=>28],
  ['id'=>2, 'name'=>'John', 'age'=>34],
  ['id'=>3, 'name'=>'Smith', 'age'=>36],
  ['id'=>3, 'name'=>'Smith', 'age'=>28],
];
```

I want filter it by column 'id', and merge the different values. I need output:

```
$arr = [
  ['id'=>1, 'name'=>'Peter,David', 'age'=>28],
  ['id'=>2, 'name'=>'John', 'age'=>34],
  ['id'=>3, 'name'=>'Smith', 'age'=>'36,28']
];
```

Is there any PHP function (such as: array_filter, array_walk, array_map,...) to do that, without looping code as below?

```
function combine_row($arr){
    $last = null;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $a){
        if ($a['id']==$last['id']){
            foreach ($a as $k=>$v) {
                if($v!==$last[$k]) {
                     $arr[$key][$k].=','.$last[$k];
                }
            }
            unset($arr[$key-1]);
        }
        $last = $a;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Phong, did you resolve this. Let me know if I should make changes to my answer

Comment: Sorry Michael, I didn't come back to view your answer, because I found the way to fix it from mysql step by using Group_concat. Anyway, your answer is so perfect. I marked it as an accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses a more functional style. Basically just a lot of the built-in `array_*` functions. This will ensure less side-effects, making your code less error prone.

The code first finds all unique _id_s. It then filters through the data and joins it in the end.

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($id) use ($arr) {
        return array_map(function ($data) {
                if (is_array($data)) return join(",", array_unique($data));
                return $data;
            }, array_reduce(
                array_filter($arr, function ($item) use ($id) { return $id === $item["id"]; }),
                function ($result, $set) { return $result = array_filter(array_merge_recursive($result, $set)); }, [ ]
            )
        );
    }, 
    array_unique(array_column($arr, "id"))
);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Peter,David
            [age] => 28
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => John
            [age] => 34
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Smith
            [age] => 36,28
        )

)
```

Using [a chainable api<sup>github</sup>](https://github.com/mblarsen/arrgh) you can achieve much more readable code:

```
$result = arr($arr)
    ->column("id")
    ->unique()
    ->map(
        function ($id) use ($arr) {
            return arr($arr)
                ->filter(function ($item) use ($id) { return $id === $item["id"]; })
                ->reduce(function ($result, $set) { return array_filter(array_merge_recursive($result, $set)); }, [])
                ->map(function ($data) {
                    if (is_array($data)) return arr($data)->unique()->join(",")->toArray();
                    return $data;
                })->toArray();
        }
    )->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $person) {
    foreach ($person as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'id') {
            $result[$person['id']][$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $result[$person['id']][$key][] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

The magic really is in `$result[$person['id']]`, which groups all items with the same id into the same result array very naturally. This also creates *arrays* for multiple values instead of merely concatenating the strings, which is a much saner data structure to work with. If you only want unique values, throw in an `array_unique` there. If you actually need to join the items with commas, use `join(',', ..)` at the end somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Check this below code,

```
function getMergerArray($arr) {
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $id = $value['id'];
        $name = $value['name'];
        $age = $value['age'];
        if (array_key_exists($id, $newArr)) {
            if (!in_array($name, $newArr[$id]['name'])) {
                $newArr[$id]['name'][] = $name;
            }
            if (!in_array($age, $newArr[$id]['age'])) {
                $newArr[$id]['age'][] = $age;
            }
            continue;
        }
        $newArr[$id]['name'][] = $name;
        $newArr[$id]['age'][] = $age;
    }
    foreach ($newArr as $key => $value) {
        $newArr[$key] = array(
            'id' => $key,
            'name' => implode(', ', $value['name']),
            'age' => implode(', ', $value['age']),
        );
    }
//    echo '<pre>';
//    print_r($newArr);
//    echo '</pre>';
    return $newArr;
}
```

Comment: Hi @deceze, Why this answer is down voted? The reason will help me in future while I post a new answer and will help others who refers to this answer. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
function merge_multidimensional($arr) {
$out = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $out[] = (object)array_merge((array)$arr2[$key], (array)$value);
}
return $out;
```

}